Firefox 'freezes' at arbitrary times on Debian 12
Firefox presents a reoccurring problem, where its graphical state suddenly stops updating. The browser doesn't outright crash; it's possible to e.g. switch tabs or write something, without anything happening visually. I have found that re-entering from the Activities overview updates the browser's display state to match the actions, but this behaviour is not consistent and does not fix the problem.
Everything else on my system appears to work fine when this happens, and rebooting seems to be the only way to fix it. I initially guessed it might be due to some obscure XOrg jank, but then encountered the same problem on my Thinkpad (Debian 12/KDE/Wayland).
Does anyone have any suggestions or similar experiences? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
(For reference, I'm running Firefox ESR v115.9.1 on Debian 12, with Gnome 43.9 and X11)

Did not have this issue so far in Debian12. Probably an extension problem. Try entering about:performance and to see which use a lot of CPU or memory.

I experienced the same issue after upgrading from Debian 11 to 12. I resolved it by removing all extensions from Firefox, which stopped the random freezing. To pinpoint the problematic extension, disable them all and enable them one by one.
